# How to open Ubuntu GUI from Command line Interface? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04. when accessing the server i need to access the GUI also for directory purpose.. 
Can someone please tell me how to go to GUI from Command line.
OR
Can someone tell me how to give path or some specific directory in command line.

Comment: Have installed a graphical desktop?

Comment: No i haven't done that. can u please help me out to do that...?

Comment: Explain "directory purpose"

Answer (score 0):

Read

http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

and especially

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0020.php

You could install a gui, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: You could install a gui, but you probably shouldn't.???

Whats  you want to tell by that statement?

Comment: see my comment above